# How does Scala ParArray overhead come？

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

According to doc, Scala ParArray is to use parallel computing inside the element operations.

I am now having a operation `def fun(index: Int)`(i is the index and would not affect the cost of the method) and using following to call

```
fun(1) // 3 ms
(0 until 2).indices.toParArray(i => fun(i)) // 6 ms
(0 until 10).indices.toParArray(i => fun(i)) // 20 ms
(0 until 50).indices.toParArray(i => fun(i)) // 35 ms
```

My machine have > 50 cores, so ideally they should all cost 3 ms

And I timed every seperated operation in (0 to 50) code, and found most of the operations cost 3~10 ms, but one cost ~30 ms and totally the operation is 35 ms.

So internally how does it work? Could we reduce this overhead?

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. Why create an `immutable.Range.Inclusive = 0 to 2` and then convert it to `immutable.Range = 0 until 3` and then convert it to `ParArray`? What's the purpose of all the conversion overhead? Why not just `ParArray.fill(3)(fun())`?

Comment: @jwvh I have to use these indices to pass them to `fun()`, and by the way, are these conversions expensive?

Comment: But the indices _aren't_ being passed to `fun()` in the posted code. If you want that, why not just `ParArray.tabulate(3)(fun(_))`? I don't know if the conversions are expensive or not, I'm just curious as to why they're there when they don't appear to serve any purpose except to complicate the overhead calculations.

Comment: @jwvh updated according to your suggestion

Comment: No. My suggestion is to use `.tabulate()()` and remove all the pointless `Range` invocations/conversions.

Comment: First the parallel collections showed to be not really useful and that is why they were moved to another library. Second, creating and coordinating threads is costly, very costly, for an operation that takes 3ms it will always be slower to make it in parallel.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez "Parallel collections showed to be not really useful", any materials to read for this?